# multiple execute on a single connection.cursor in django. Is it safe?

Tags: python, django, database-connection, database-cursor, django-database

I am opening a cursor with connection.cursor executing a bunch of deletes then closing the cursor. It works, but I am not sure if it has any side effect. Would appreciate any feedback.

```
from django.db import connection
c=connection.cursor()
try:
    c.execute('delete from table_a')
    c.execute('delete from table_b')
    ...
finally:
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are not executing these SQL statements in the transaction, you may encounter confusing states (for example, data was deleted from `table_a`, but not from `table_b`).

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#sequences-of-custom-sql-queries) says about this particular situation:

> If you’re executing several custom SQL queries in a row, each one now
>   runs in its own transaction, instead of sharing the same “automatic
>   transaction”. If you need to enforce atomicity, you must wrap the
>   sequence of queries in atomic().

So, results of each `execute()` call are committed right after it, but we want them either all to pass, or all to fail - as a single one set of changes.

Wrap the view with a [`transacton.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) decorator:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def my_view(request):
    c = connection.cursor()
    try:
        c.execute('delete from table_a')
        c.execute('delete from table_b')
    finally:
        c.close()
```

Note that `atomic()` and the whole [new transaction management system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) were introduced in Django 1.6.

If you are using Django < 1.6, apply [`transaction.commit_on_success`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success) decorator.

Comment: As far as I understand this would happen also if I open and close a cursor for each delete. I was more worried that the cursor was really thought as a one use object, even if it worked multiple times and failed to clean up resources if used like the above.

Comment: @DanieleBernardini got it, the way you use the cursor is perfectly fine.

Comment: After a lot of searching, breaking my head, I am glad I finally found the solution. This not only helped the proper synchronization, but also reduced my process execution time. +1. Thanks.